# Inequality with norm

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Why is it true $||Aj|| \le ||j||$? 
Where $A$ is $n \times n$ matrix and $j$ is a vector.

Edit:
matrix $A$ is given by formula $a_{ij}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{d(i)\cdot d(j)}}$ if $ij \in E(G)$ and $0$ otherwise.

$A$ is called the degree adjacency matrix of graph $G$ and $d(i)$ is degree of vertex $i$.

Comment: What is $E$, $d(i)$,  $d(j)$?

Comment: $A$ is called the degree adjacency matrix of graph $G$ and $d(i)$ is degree of vertex $i$.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly false.  You can replace $A$ by $kA$ and let $k \to \infty$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: and after edited?